# raise an error in sql server severity higher than 18

Tags: sql-server, errors, raiserror

I can easily raise user defined errors where severity is not higher than 18. When is higher, I get this error

> Error severity levels greater than 18 can only be specified by members of the 
>   sysadmin role, using the WITH LOG option.

I have access to sysadmin role, so can someone specify the syntax for raising errors WITH LOG option.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`WITH` is an optional clause that goes at the end of the `RAISERROR`. A few examples:

```
RAISERROR('Oops', 10, 1)
RAISERROR('Oops', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT
RAISERROR('Oops', 10, 1) WITH SETERROR

RAISERROR('Oops', 19, 1) -- Fails with "Error severity levels greater than 18..."
RAISERROR('Oops', 19, 1) WITH LOG -- OK
```

Remember that severities of 20 and above will terminate the connection (won't even jump to a `CATCH`).

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the @with_log parameter while using sp_addmessage sproc

```
sp_addmessage 50001, 19, 'Test Message', @with_log='True'
```